# Problema con axios y flask

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, axios

Tengo un problema al hacer una peticion a mi rest api

Python:

```
app.route('/bodega/show/specific', methods=['GET'])
def show_bodega_specific():
    try:
        data = request.json
        id_bodega = data["idBodega"]
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM bodega join item on bodega.id_item = item.id_item join usuarios on bodega.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario WHERE id_bodega = %s", (id_bodega)
        )
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return jsonify(data), 202
    except:
        return "Error al extraer datos", 500
```

React:

```
UNSAFE_componentWillMount(){
        let config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        }

        Axios.get('http://localhost:80/bodega/show/specific', {
            idBodega: this.state.id
        }, config).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({datos: response.data,});
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
```

y siempre me regresa el código 500
pero si pruebo el query de sql si funciona bien 
creo que es a la hora de extraer los parametros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio el problema es que estas empleando mal [`Axios.get`](https://github.com/axios/axios#example), por lo que el `idBodega` no se está enviando.

### Solución:

Para enviar parámetros por `get`, debes indicar la priopiedad `params` en la `config`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
    let config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        params: {
          idBodega: this.state.id
        }
    }

    Axios.get('http://localhost:80/bodega/show/specific', config)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({datos: response.data,});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

**PD:** En `Python` deberías validar que `data["idBodega"]` existe, y por que no, que cumple un formato específico.